# Stream Extensions to convert Stream content into String or Byte array

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Using C# 10 I am creating `Stream` extensions to get content into a String or Byte array.

Something similar to [`File.ReadAllTextAsync` in Microsoft's Net 6.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltextasync?view=net-6.0)

```
public static async Task<string> ReadAllTextAsync(this Stream stream). {
  string result;

  using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
     result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }

  return result;
}

public static async Task<byte[]> ReadAllBytesAsync(this Stream stream) {
  
  using (var content = new MemoryStream()) {
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096).ConfigureAwait(false);
    while (read > 0) {
      content.Write(buffer, 0, read);
      read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return content.ToArray();
  }
}

public static async Task<List<string>> ReadAllLinesAsync(this Stream stream) {
  var lines = new List<string>();
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    string line;
    while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null) {
      lines.Add(line);
    }
  }
  return lines;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I am not sure about the `ConfigureAwait(false)` that I picked on some code online.

Comment: For `ReadAllBytesAsync` I would use `CopyToAsync` instead of manually handling the buffers.

Comment: How about a `ReadLinesAsync` returning an `IAsyncEnumerable<string>` to avoid having to store all of the lines in memory if it's not required?

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative for the `ReadAllBytesAsync` is

```cs
public static async Task<byte[]> ReadAllBytesAsync(this Stream stream) 
{
    switch (stream)
    {
        case MemoryStream mem:
            return mem.ToArray();
        default:
            using var m = new MemoryStream();
            await stream.CopyToAsync(m);
            return mem.ToArray();
    }
}
```

For the `ReadAllLinesAsync`, the async stream in C# 8 can make the code cleaner:

```cs
public IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadAllLinesAsync(this Stream stream)
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream)
    while (await reader.ReadLineAsync() is { } line)
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

notice that the empty brace `{ }` here is actually a property pattern that is only available after C# 8, it checks whether `reader.ReadLineAsync()` is `null`, if it's not, assign it to the `line` variable.

Usage:

```cs
var lines = await stream.ReadAllLinesAsync();
await foreach (var line in lines) 
{
    // write your own logic here
}
```

**P.S.:**

The `ConfigureAwait(false)` is kinda useless if your app is single-threaded like console apps, it instructs the `awaiter` not to capture the `SynchronizationContext` and let continuation run on the thread that runs the `await` statement, this method is useful when you're writing a library or SDK, since your user may use your library in a GUI application, and the combination of block waiting such as calling `Task.Wait()` and the capturing of `SynchronizationContext` often leads to deadlock, and `ConfigureAwait(false)` solves this. For detail explanation see [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)